# Flutter Will not run on IOS Simulator - Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures

Tags: flutter

I upgraded to Flutter 2.5.0 and now I cannot run on an IOS simulator, from either Android Studio or the command line.

It fails with the error

```
Runner.xcodeproj: error: The linked framework 'Pods_Runner.framework' is missing one or more architectures
    required by this target: arm64. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

- I can manage to run on the Simulator from XCode without an issue
- I can run on a device from Android Studio or command line

I have tried

- restarting the simulator.
- cleaning the build folder
- upgrading Cocoapods to 1.11.1

Flutter Doctor says that everything is fine.

----------------- Edit ------------------

The situation Eventually Resolved Itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem because of ARM64 for me. This helped for me.

Be sure to open `.xcworkspace`.

Adding "arm64" to Project -> Build Settings -> Excluded Architecture

The reason why this might have been happened is because Xcode has been updated to a newer version. You gotta love Xcode..

Comment: I did check this issue but it was not the problem.

Comment: This solved for me.. =^